# jquery cycle slider height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to make the slider on  [this page](http://apacks.businesscatalyst.com/sandbox-2#)  behave responsively. However, it seems it requires a fixed height on the container, otherwise it does not display the entire slide.

Is there a way (other than going to jquery cycle 2 plugin which I am not allowed to do) to declare a height:auto and still display the entire image? I initially suspected it's something to do with floats, but they are all cleared and still not working.

If I force overflow:show on the wrapper (#industries-slider) I run into issues with the #nav which does move with the overflow.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

**Update**: responsive, not adaptative. I know I can use media queries to adjust the height, but on exotic displays (and on browser resize which is how its being tested, there is a visible jump of the #nav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, set position: absolute again.
You can set the height of #industries-slider1 using jQuery.

```
 //Find the max height of items
        var heights = $(".slide-item").map(function ()
        {
            return $(this).height();
        }).get(),
        maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
 //Set #industries-slider1 height
        $('#industries-slider1').height(maxHeight);
```

Comment: if I do that, when I slide to the next container, that displays on it's relative position until the transition happens so that makes a snap at the end of the transition.